# Disable image on click html bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 images which allows users to select only 1 image out of 4.

When the user clicks on any image, the clicked image along with other 3 images should be disabled and the same user has to again click on the 'clicked' image to enable the image.

Basically i need to make the images look like its Clickable (with some borders or something..), Then onclick of image say 'A' the user gets a message (as shown from the when_i_click_carrom()), post which all the images (B,C,D) should be disabled (for that user only), and  same user has to click on disabled image 'A' to enable it.

NOTE: Only the Image A should be disabled for the current user and other users, but other images B,C,D should be clickable for other users, until the current user enables the image A

```
 ...
 <script>
    var when_i_click_carrom = function(){
        alert('You selected Carrom!');
    }
</script>
...
 <div class="container">


    <div class="grid_layout_row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="sidebar"><img src="images/carrom.jpg" alt="carrom" class="img-responsive" onclick="when_i_click_carrom();"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="sidebar"><img src="images/foosball.jpg" alt="foosball" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="sidebar"><img src="images/table-tennis.jpg" alt="table-tennis" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="sidebar"><img src="images/chess.jpg" alt="chess" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the code that you have written to get the intended function?

Comment: What do you mean with "disabled for other users" and "clickable for other users"?

Comment: Do you mean that site should be live-updating and disable image from all other site visitors someone clicks it?

Comment: A user has option of selecting only 1 image at a time. ie) Suppose User A clicks on Image A, All images are disabled for him.  Once image A is disabled by User A , Only Image A is globally disabled for all users(But Other Images B,C,D are accessible to other users, but not for user A) and Image A can be accessible to others only when User A deselects it ...

Answer (score 2):

Try with `querySelectorAll` .Img not have a default disable attribute .So try with class

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.img-responsive').forEach(function(a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.disabled = this.disabled == true ? false : true;
    this.classList.toggle('disable')
    //console.log(this.disabled)
  })
})
```

```css
.disable {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid_layout_row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="sidebar"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="carrom" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="sidebar"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="foosball" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="sidebar"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="table-tennis" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="sidebar"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="chess" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out over here.

```
jQuery(".sidebar").click(function(){
if(jQuery(".sidebar").hasClass("disabled")){
    jQuery(".sidebar").removeClass("disabled");
}else{
    jQuery(".sidebar").addClass("disabled");
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ott5wanq/4/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap, you can use image buttons and use disabled class for all items when one of them clicked. I created an example :

HTML :

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="grid_layout_row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="sidebar"><button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary myBtn" onclick="imgClicked()">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" alt="carrom" class="img-responsive">
        </button></div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="sidebar"><button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary myBtn" onclick="imgClicked()" >
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2" alt="carrom" class="img-responsive">
        </button></div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="sidebar"><button type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary myBtn" onclick="imgClicked()">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3" alt="carrom" class="img-responsive">
        </button></div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="sidebar"><button type="button" id="btn4" class="btn btn-primary myBtn" onclick="imgClicked()">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5" alt="carrom" class="img-responsive">
        </button></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Script ( using Jquery ) :

```
function imgClicked (){
    $('.myBtn').addClass('disabled');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/80u0pbyw/2/